# How to test Mongodb find,findOne function using Jest in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, jestjs

I have been trying to write test cases for mongodb find,findOne,UpdateMany system library functions that I am using in my code. But couldnt able to find right way to test mongo functions.

I have tried to mock implementaion and return values of find,findOne,UpdateMany mongo function using jest.fn() but either the test case is failing or I am stuck with "TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined" mongoDB error. Need good help on right way to test find, findOne functions of mongoDB .

I am passing mongo_con.find function to myFuncImpl()

Connection/Config File:

```
let mongo_conn = await MongoUtil.createMongoConnection(config.MONGO_COL_NAME);

myService.myFuncImpl(context,mongo_conn.find) // passing as a function
```

Implementation file:

```
myFuncImpl = async (mongo_con_find:any) {

  let result = await mongo_con_find({ }, { projection: {_id: 0, Name: 1 }}).toArray();

  return result;
}
```

In my jest Test file:

```
test("for myFuncImpl()", async () => {

 let mongo_con_find = jest.fn(() => ({ toArray: _ =>[...DummyMongoResponse]}));

 output_data = await myService.myFuncImpl(context_data,mongo_con_find)
 expect(mongo_con_find).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // giving me 0

}
```

Comment: Do you want to try to test the `myService.myFuncImpl` to execute the function passed to it as a second argument?

Comment: @nnfans - yes, as a callback function. I referred this - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions which says you can mock and test as callback function.

Comment: have you try my answer below?

Comment: yes, its working. thank you.

Comment: please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return promise in order to use await

```
test("for myFuncImpl()", async () => {

  let mongo_con_find = jest.fn(
    () => ({
      toArray: () => (new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve([...DummyMongoResponse])
      })

  output_data = await myService.myFuncImpl(context_data,mongo_con_find)
  expect(mongo_con_find).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // giving me 0

}
```